# how to create sed script file for editing

Tags: sed

I have a task to create a sed script file which can translate from English to morse code. but first the morse code file is to be put in the sed script and transform into a file and that can be used to translate english ito morse code . so i tried this way. i made file in sed script as follows

```
s/[Aa]/\.-/g
s/[Bb]/-\.\.\./g
s/[Cc]/-\.-\./g
s/[Dd]/-\.\./g
s/[Ee]/\./g
s/[Ff]/\.\.-\./g
s/[Gg]/--\./g
s/[Hh]/\.\.\.\./g
s/[Ii]/\.\./g
s/[Jj]/\.---/g
s/[Kk]/-\.-/g
s/[Ll]/\.-\.\./g
s/[Mm]/--/g
s/[Nn]/-\./g
s/[Oo]/---/g
s/[Pp]/\.--\./g
s/[Qq]/--\.-/g
s/[Rr]/\.-\./g
s/[Ss]/\.\.\./g
s/[Tt]/-/g
s/[Uu]/\.\.-/g
s/[Vv]/\.\.\.-/g
s/[Ww]/\.--/g
s/[Xx]/-\.\.-/g
s/[Yy]/-\.--/g
s/[Zz]/--\.\./g
s/0/------/g
s/1/\.---/g
s/2/\.\.---/g
s/3/\.\.\.--/g
s/4/\.\.\.\.-/g
s/5/\.\.\.\.\./g
s/6/-\.\.\.\./g
s/7/--\.\.\./g
s/8/---\.\./g
s/9/----\./g
```

but eventually i should have a script file which can be used to translate from english to morse code. i am stuck here

Comment: bonus points to create another sed script to convert morse code back into English

Comment: Re: _`"bonus points to create another sed script to convert morse code back into English "`_ With OP's conversion, converting back to English will not give him expected result until he specify a unique character at first or in end or in a specific position between that once he want tell that to decoder it's can understand the character or position of specific character. @ScottStensland

Comment: Note that Morse code has three symbols: dit, dah and break, and break is used as delimiter. Otherwise, "a" would be indistinguishable from "et", "o" indistingushable from "ttt" or "mt" and so on.

Comment: Your codes for `0` and `1` are wrong, I think.

Answer (score 6):

You are done.

Just run your script on a file:

```
sed -f script.sed inputfile
```

Example:

```
$ cat file
Kusalananda
$ sed -f script.sed file
-.-..-....-.-...--..--.-...-
```

The only thing worth commenting on in your script is that the dots don't need to be escaped when they occur in the replacement text, and the script does not handle punctuation. You may additionally want to end each code with a space or some other character for easier decoding (`s/\(.\)/\1 /g` would do that if you ran that as a first instruction).

You may also bypass having to use `[Aa]` for every letter by letting the first instruction be

```
s/\([A-Z]\)/\L\1/g
```

This would require GNU `sed` though, but would convert all letters to lowercase.

In non-GNU `sed`'s, the following would lowercase all letters:

```
y/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/
```

If you wished, you could add

```
#!/usr/bin/sed -f
```

as the very top line of the script and make it executable.  This would allow you to run the script as

```
./script.sed file
```

provided that the path to `sed` is correct on the `#!`-line.  You could also get rid of the `.sed` extension on the filename, of course. It does nothing.

Comment: yes i did ran it like this                                                                           sed -f script.sed inputfile     ,but the problem is i have to make it another script file so that the second one can translate not this one. which makes me confuse

Comment: @Somojel I believe that you will have to describe what this other script should be doing, because you haven't mentioned this in the question.

Comment: the question says that sed should read the morse code file and change it to translate.sed file and that translate.sed file is then used as used as a sed script to translate files from english to morse code.

Comment: @Somojel What is "the morse code file"?