# how to make two scripts in sed. one after the other

Tags: sed

How can we use a file to make a script in `sed` and then using that script again to translate the text? For example, 
if we have a morse code file to be translated in `sed` and again use that script to translate English text to morse code.

Comment: Please give an example of the input, the expected output and why do you think that you need an intermediate file. You already know how to write an `sed` script to translate text to morse code directly, the same way you could translate back with a fixed script. Why do you think you would need a dynamical script?

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know what a morse code file is (but I remember [your previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/438107/how-to-create-sed-script-file-for-editing)), I suppose it would be a script like

```
#!/bin/sh

# Some code that creates the sed script "translate.sed"
# goes here. We can't really know how to do this because
# we don't know what a "morse code file" is.

# Run the just-created script on a file which was
# given on the command line:
sed -f translate.sed "$1"
```

If this script is called `do_translate.sh`, you would run it as

```
$ ./do_translate.sh text_file.txt
```

where `text_file.txt` is a file that you would want to translate into Morse code.

However, it seems strange that you would want to create the `sed` script every time you run the above script.  I would probably create `translate.sed` once and for all and use that directly, as I [mentioned in my previous reply to you](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/438114/116858).